# Background with opacity :before and :after anchor

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to style `<a/>`-tags as buttons. The background is cutted in three parts:

```
[before][text][after]
```

**Problem 1:**

The backgrounds of `[before]` and `[after]` are overlying `[text]`. If the opacity of `[before]`/`[after]` isn't 100% or the background-images have transparent pixels, the background of `[text]` becomes visible. That's why I need them *outside* the anchor.

**Problem 2:**

I float all three elements but need to clear the floating to be able to continue with other tags as usual.

Here's the **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/WdUdy/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" class="button">I'm a button</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #616161;
    color: #E0E0E0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    float: left;    
}

a.button:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #A50063;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;    
}

a.button:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #A50063;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}
```

I'd appreciate a code snippet, tutorial or any other help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/WdUdy/2/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WdUdy/4/

You can place absolutely-positioned blocks before and after your relatively-positioned text, with a height of 100%.

```
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background: #616161;
    color: #E0E0E0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    float: left;
    position: relative;    
}

a.button:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #A50063;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -30px;   
}

a.button:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #A50063;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cannot see any difference on the fiddle. `before` and `after` are still overlying the `text` (take a look at the color differences).

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is a simple matter of adding a span inside the anchor, around the text, and basing the pseudo elements on that?

```
<a href="" class="button"><span>I'm a button</span></a>
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Q5NgA/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried without using pseudo before and after. Take a look:

```
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #616161;
    color: #E0E0E0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    float: left;  
    border-left: solid 30px rgba(165, 0, 99, 0.3);
    border-right: solid 30px rgba(165, 0, 99, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but as already mentioned, there could be background-images instead of simple colors. Your solution only works with plain colors, unfortunately.